# In a windows command prompt, how do you make python translate a print command as an argument for a program?

Tags: python, c, windows, command-line, pipeline

I have built a very small C program that accepts arguments from the command line to experience with buffer overflows. I am trying to overwrite the stack's function return value with a specific hexadecimal value. Instead of looking through the ASCII chart, I know I can use python to translate hex values to ASCII for me.

I've only found documentation for Linux that havn't worked for me on Windows.

[Run function from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/run-function-from-the-command-line)

[Input Hex into argv[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084894/input-hex-into-argv1)

./myProgram $(python -c "print '\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'") (from above links)

What I have tried :

> myprogram.exe ($python -c print('\xe9\x14\x40\x00'))
>
> myprogram.exe `$python -c print('\xe9\x14\x40\x00')`
>
> myprogram.exe `python -c "print('\xe9\x14\x40\x00')"`

Result should be:

> myprogram.exe [argv1]

use python's print function to input value into argv1

> myprogram.exe é[]@

***[] is not a printable character. It's hex 14 in the ASCII table***

Comment: Try this https://superuser.com/questions/289344/is-there-something-like-command-substitution-in-windows-cli

Comment: @JL2210 Yes, that's exactly what my question is. However, just like the author of the post mentionned, even if you do have Pearl/Python packages installed, in a windows CMD prompt, if you do >myprogram.exe [python script here]:  the script isn't evaluated. It takes it directly as arguments for the myprogram executable. I've read the documentation about the Python C switch which is exactly what I need but I have no clue about how to feed the output as an argument to an executable from the command line

Comment: @NathanHunt Better duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows